# How to autostart a Bada 2.0 app after the boot?

Tags: bada

I think auto-starting a Bada app just immediately after the device boots up was not possible with pre-2.0 firmware/sdk. I'm wondering if it's possible with 2.0?

Answer (score 1):

Bada 2.0 introduced conditional app launch, you can define different condition under which your app will be launched by the system.
However these conditions does not include what you are looking for, this is a good thing because:

1. It's dangerous to have an application that automatically starts when the phone boots up
2. Many apps registered to launch when the phone boots may slow down the boot process itself

Here's the link to the [documentation for the conditional apps launch on bada](http://developer.bada.com/help_2.0/index.jsp?topic=/com.osp.cppappprogramming.help/html/dev_guide/app/registering_launch_condition.htm)